# Electrical motors' properties regarding Stall torque

Tags: motor, output, torque

Is there's any way, or any type of electrical motor, that can have a Stall torque, meaning a torque produced while having its output rotational speed lowered or zero, without damaging the motor? like with our arm we can hold a cup in the air, having the constant force output to hold the cup in its place, and we can even add water to the cup, increasing the necesary force output from our arm, without damaging the arm. Is this possible for any type of electric actuation?

Answer (score 1):

A motor that is designed to provide torque continuously at stall is called a torque motor. Torque motors can be designed for use with or without electronic controllers. However an electronic controller with shaft position feedback is required to hold a fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

It is and all motors can hold a level of torque indefinitely. The level however is dependent on the motor and the associated controller.

An electrical controller would be needed to regulate the current to a level that a particular motor can survive at. During stall copper losses dominate.

To give you an idea... A particular motor I have reaches dangerous temp levels at peak torque & peak speed after one minute. The same motor at 10% torque and very low Rpm takes two hours to settle out at just under 100C

Answer (score 0):

A stepping motor will provide a variable torque (from zero to +/- limits) to hold a static position. Once you exceed that holding torque, the motor will spin (and inertia will help it get last subsequent torque humps) and your cup will end up on the floor. The holding torque is generally proportional to the current, too much current and the motor overheats. To make it move you vary the currents through the coils.

If you want a constant torque, more or less independent of shaft RPM, there are motors designed to do that, as Charles points out. A constant current through a DC motor does something like that.

An AC or DC servo motor with feedback can be controlled to act similarly to a stepper, with large potential performance advantages (and usually a significant cost penalty).